# Reading Java system.out.print via Python subprocess

Tags: java, python

I am running a Python script that runs a Java class that requires nondeterministic user input:

```
import sys
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen("java myclass", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    inline = p.stdout.readline()
    if not inline:
        break

sys.stdout.write(inline)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

When output is displayed using `System.out.print()`, the output is displayed properly.  However, when a prompt for user input is printed with `System.out.print()`, the output is not displayed.  I tried switching `p.stdout.readline()` to `p.stdout.read()`, but then no output is displayed.  Is there a way to display an input prompt that does not have a carriage return?

**EDIT**

For example, if the Java class contains the following:

```
System.out.println("Message 1);
System.out.println("Message 2);
System.out.print("Enter a number:")
```

Running the pure Java code would display all 3 lines.

The code running through Python would only display the following:

```
Message 1
Message 2
```

Comment: You can use `strip` to remove the carriage return : `inline = p.stdout.readline().strip()`

Comment: I am confused. All System.out prints are done to STDOUT, so reading it should be no different.  However, a System.in is reading from STDIN, so you would have to write out the "user input" with the appropriate combination of keys to indicate the input had stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/java", "MyClass"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p1.stdout.read()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the prompt using this: